# Solving Equations in Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Solve simultaneously:  $(xax)^3 =bx$ and $x^2a=(xa)^{-1}$. This is an exercise from 'A book of Abstract Algebra' by Pinter. Chapter 4: Elementary Properties of Groups.

I just need help on getting started. Please, no complete answer.

Comment: On a side note, how are you liking Pinter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
(xax)^3 = xaxxaxxax \\
x^2a = xxa \\
(xa)^{-1} = a^{-1}x^{-1} \\
aa^{-1} = a^{-1}a = xx^{-1} = x^{-1}xe \\
$$

Further notice
$$
xa\underbrace{xxa}_{x^2a}\underbrace{xxa}_{x^2a}x = bx \iff xa\underbrace{xxa}_{x^2a}\underbrace{xxa}_{x^2a} = b
$$

Answer (score 1):

Write the first equation as $xaxxaxxax=bx$ and note the double $x$es, what do they factor to? Then substitute.